# space does not work in input tag with php

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following code in my php file.

```
<?php 
    $text = $_GET['name'];
    $image_url="dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";
    $text= $_GET['name'];



        $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
        $blue = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 59, 89, 152);

        $font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
        imagettftext($jpg_image, 22, 0, 278,37, $blue, $font_path, $text);


        imagejpeg($jpg_image,$image_url);
        imagedestroy($jpg_image);


    ?>
```

In this code I'm getting text from the input tag from my html file`$_GET['name'];` and I'm getting the image from the dump because I want it like that only.This ode is perfectly working but when I put "space" in the input tag it does not show me any image for eg:- `name surname` the space between name and surname when I'm giving space between any word it does't show me any result it is working fine without space hope you find solution.

Comment: So you're saying that the value of `$image_url` is wrong when `$text` contains a space character? Is that correct?

Comment: BTW, You can bypass it by replacing spaces with `-` or `_`.

Comment: what happen if I put it on a website I don't want to say users to use `-` instead of space

Comment: @TZHX You are saying right

Comment: So, do you understand what the `rawurlencode` method is doing? And can you extrapolate from that to see what the problem is, and how to solve it?

Comment: @TZHX I don't know that what `rawurlencode` is doing i think it is giving the name which is written on the url for the dump image

Comment: You don't need to set `$text` twice. But this is not the problem. Add `print_r($text);` and `print_r($image_url);` where the second `$text=` declaration is. Check the values that are returned.

Comment: @RST can you give me a proper answer

Comment: It's hard to provide an answer without debugging the values of the variables.

Comment: @OfirBaruch The code which I have provided is perfectly a working code but when we enter any text with space containing in between them then it stop responding and does not show any image

Comment: What I wanted to check is how the values appeared when there is a space in the name. The only way to do that is by using `echo` or `print()` or `var_dump`. The idea of stackoverflow is to help you with your code and educate you if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Leave all the things just see what I have done I have tested it it is working well.

```
<?php 
$text = $_GET['name'];
$image_url="dump/".urlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";
$text= $_GET['name'];



    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 59, 89, 152);

    $font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 22, 0, 278,37, $blue, $font_path, $text);


    imagejpeg($jpg_image,$image_url);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);


?>
```

just removed the `raw` from `$image_url="dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";`
and made it `$image_url="dump/".urlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";`